# Can't resize UIImageView between iPhone4 and iPhone5

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am making an app where I need to  display an image in a modal screen. In my xib, I made the UIImage view the full size of the screen. when the image displays, it is centered within the screen. This works fine on the iPhone5. However, When I revert back to the 4s to Test, I cant seem to shrink the Image view no matter what I do to make the image centered in the screen resulting in the image displaying half way off the page because the image view is too large for the screen. the scroll view seems to resize correctly and I am not sure why the image wiew will not.

Screen shot of the symptom on the 4s[image]
Relevant code below:

```
[self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale animated:YES];
[self.myView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[self.scrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[self.imageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.myImage];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)  name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];

[self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale animated:YES];
CGSize imageSize  =  [self currentScreenBoundsDependOnOrientation];

self.imageView.frame = self.myView.bounds ;
self.scrollView.frame = self.myView.bounds;

imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
```

Comment: Did you tried resizing the image. I guess this will fix

Comment: What are the resulting frame values on iphone 4 and iphone 5?

Comment: that is what it was. the main view frame was too large so I just fixed it depending on screen size. thanks  @Sulthan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that could go wrong.

1. Make sure `autoresizesSubviews` is set to `NO` on the scrollView or `autoresizingMask` on the `imageView` is set to none (you don't want the `imageView.frame` to change when `scrollView.frame` changes).
2. Are you sure you want the image centered? If an image is centered and the image view is smaller than it (which is probably the case on iphone 4), then obviously part of the image will be hidden. Are you sure you don't want the `contentMode` be set to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`? Or even better, are you sure you don't want the `imageView` to have the same size as the image and use the `scrollView` to view the image?

Comment: Sulthan, yes I do set the aspect scale to fit.. however since the imageview is bigger on the 4 and will not resize to 460 my image is half off the screen. What I meant was I want the image to be centered in the screen, not neccessarily just the view. Also, If i do that than the image is REALLY big, do I have to resize the image manually at that point?

Comment: the results are the same..